# Making an array case insensitive

Tags: php

The code below returns a table with a row for every word or number that appears in `$commentstring`. Each word or number appears as `$word` in the table below. It's case sensitive.  How can I make it case insensitive?

```
$words = explode(" ", $commentstring);


    $result = array();

    arsort($words);



foreach($words as $word) {

    if(!is_numeric($word)){
        $result[$word]++;
        arsort($result);
    }

}




    echo "<table>";


        $blacklist = array('the', 'is', 'a');

foreach($result as $word => $count1)
{
    if (in_array($word, $blacklist)) continue;


    echo '<tr>';    
    echo '<td>';
    echo "$word";
    echo '</td>';

    echo '<td>';
    echo "$count1 ";
    echo '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';

    }

    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: in_array is notoriously slow, because is sorts the array each time. It's several orders of magnitude faster to `array_flip` on your array you need to check, then use `isset` to find if the word exists.

Comment: What would the code for that look like?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (in_array($word, $blacklist)) continue;
```

to:

```
if (in_array(strtolower($word), $blacklist)) continue;
```

Comment: + every word in `$blacklist` must be in lower case too.

Comment: @clime Which can be done easily with `$wrods = array_map(function($el){ return strtolower($el); }, $words);` (Not the function can only be inline in PHP 5.3+

Comment: @cppl: ye but he is probably going to replace it with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this will do exactly what you want, and it is several times faster as I changed `in_array` to use the `array_flip` & `isset` trick:

```
$words = explode(' ', $commentstring);
$result = array();
arsort($words);

foreach($words as $word) {
    if(!is_numeric($word)){
        $result[$word]++;
        arsort($result);
    }
}

echo "<table>";

$blacklist = 'the is a';
$blacklist = explode(' ', strtolower($blacklist));
$blacklist = array_flip($blacklist);

foreach($result as $word => $count1)
{
    if (isset($blacklist[strtolower($word)])) continue;

    echo '<tr>';    
    echo '<td>';
    echo "$word";
    echo '</td>';

    echo '<td>';
    echo "$count1 ";
    echo '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but you could use iexplode (a case insensitive version of explode, which i have used in the past when explode just won't cut it.).

```
<?PHP

function iexplode($delimiter, $string, $limit = false)
{
    /*

    explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )

    If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of
    limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string .

    If the limit parameter is negative, all components except the last -limit are returned.

    If the limit parameter is zero, then this is treated as 1.

    Return Values

    If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE. 
    If delimiter contains a value that is not contained in string and a negative limit is used, 
    then an empty array will be returned. For any other limit , an array containing string will be returned.



    */
    if (($delimiter === false) || ($delimiter == "")) {
        return false;
    }

    $first_token_at = stripos($string, $delimiter);

    if ($first_token_at === false) {
        if ($limit < 0) {
            return array();
        }
        return array(
            $string
        );
    }

    $tokenlen = strlen($delimiter);
    $copypos  = ($first_token_at == 0) ? $tokenlen : 0;
    $result   = array();


    $SCAN  = strtoupper($string);
    $DELIM = strtoupper($delimiter);

    $work_array = $limit !== false ? explode($DELIM, $SCAN, $limit) : explode($DELIM, $SCAN);

    foreach ($work_array as $work) {
        $worklen    = strlen($work);
        $this_chunk = substr($string, $copypos, $worklen);
        array_push($result, $this_chunk);
        $copypos += ($worklen + $tokenlen);
    }

    return $result;
}



function test_iexplode()
{
    $testinput = "oranges and apples AND bananas And tomatoes aND artichokes";

    $test1 = '$testoutput1 = iexplode("aNd",$testinput);';
    $test2 = '$testoutput2 = iexplode("and",$testinput,1);';
    $test3 = '$testoutput3 = iexplode("And",$testinput,2);';
    $test4 = '$testoutput4 = iexplode("AND",$testinput,-1);';

    eval($test1);
    eval($test2);
    eval($test3);
    eval($test4);

    echo var_export(compact(testinput, test1, testoutput1, test2, testoutput2, test3, testoutput3, test4, testoutput4), true);



    $controlinput = "oranges and apples and bananas and tomatoes and artichokes";

    $test1 = '$testoutput1 = explode("and",$controlinput);';
    $test2 = '$testoutput2 = explode("and",$controlinput,1);';
    $test3 = '$testoutput3 = explode("and",$controlinput,2);';
    $test4 = '$testoutput4 = explode("and",$controlinput,-1);';

    eval($test1);
    eval($test2);
    eval($test3);
    eval($test4);


    echo var_export(compact(controlinput, test1, testoutput1, test2, testoutput2, test3, testoutput3, test4, testoutput4), true);

}
/*
array(
    'testinput' => 'oranges and apples AND bananas And tomatoes aND artichokes',
    'test1' => '$testoutput1 = iexplode("aNd",$testinput);',
    'testoutput1' => array(
        0 => 'oranges ',
        1 => ' apples ',
        2 => ' bananas ',
        3 => ' tomatoes ',
        4 => ' artichokes'
    ),
    'test2' => '$testoutput2 = iexplode("and",$testinput,1);',
    'testoutput2' => array(
        0 => 'oranges ',
        1 => ' apples ',
        2 => ' bananas ',
        3 => ' tomatoes ',
        4 => ' artichokes'
    ),
    'test3' => '$testoutput3 = iexplode("And",$testinput,2);',
    'testoutput3' => array(
        0 => 'oranges ',
        1 => ' apples ',
        2 => ' bananas ',
        3 => ' tomatoes ',
        4 => ' artichokes'
    ),
    'test4' => '$testoutput4 = iexplode("AND",$testinput,-1);',
    'testoutput4' => array(
        0 => 'oranges ',
        1 => ' apples ',
        2 => ' bananas ',
        3 => ' tomatoes ',
        4 => ' artichokes'
    )
);

array(
    'controlinput' => 'oranges and apples and bananas and tomatoes and artichokes',
    'test1' => '$testoutput1 = explode("and",$controlinput);',
    'testoutput1' => array(
        0 => 'oranges ',
        1 => ' apples ',
        2 => ' bananas ',
        3 => ' tomatoes ',
        4 => ' artichokes'
    ),
    'test2' => '$testoutput2 = explode("and",$controlinput,1);',
    'testoutput2' => array(
        0 => 'oranges and apples and bananas and tomatoes and artichokes'
    ),
    'test3' => '$testoutput3 = explode("and",$controlinput,2);',
    'testoutput3' => array(
        0 => 'oranges ',
        1 => ' apples and bananas and tomatoes and artichokes'
    ),
    'test4' => '$testoutput4 = explode("and",$controlinput,-1);',
    'testoutput4' => array(
        0 => 'oranges ',
        1 => ' apples ',
        2 => ' bananas ',
        3 => ' tomatoes '
    )
);
*/


?>
```